How do you resize an image in Android
I want to know two things please:
I would like to resize an image in Jetpack Compose but I get an error:
Unresolved reference: size
What am I supposed to import because I imported this
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier

Where can I see what can be imported because this is surely the biggest headache knowing what to import.
Also how do I use the colors I specify in my colors.xml file located in the res directory.
I want to use the colors I have in my resource file called colors.xml
Here is my composable trying to set an image size and a button I want to give a background color to:
@Composable
fun Logo(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.slipsol),
        contentDescription = "The SlipSol logo",
        modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
    )
}

@Composable
fun FrontButtons() {
    Column {
        Logo()

        Button(
            onClick = {},
            modifier = Modifier.width(200.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Green)
        ) {
            Text("See Promotions")
        }
    }
}

Help is appreciated thanks

use this import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter

@Composable
fun ResizedImage(
    painter: Painter,
    width: Int,
    height: Int,
    contentDescription: String?,
) {
    Image(
        painter = painter,
        contentDescription = contentDescription,
        modifier = Modifier.size(width.dp, height.dp) // Resize image
    )
}

your import seems fine may be you have done something wrong in calling modifier.

Android Studio has a feature called Power Save mode. I turned that off and now it works. The IDE is broken for sure. How do I align an image center pls?

use box to set property like alighment Box(
modifier = Modifier.size(width.dp, height.dp),
contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
Image(
painter = painter,
contentDescription = contentDescription,
contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
)
}

As rajeev ranjan said, correct one is androidx.compose.foundation.Image, so you are using correct import.
I see that you have another question about align image in center.
You can simply put image inside a Box that have a content alignment, here is a code example:
Box(
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.some_image),
        contentDescription = "The SlipSol logo",
        modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
    )
}

About colors, you can use colorResource() method, and your code will be like this:
Button(
        onClick = {},
        modifier = Modifier.width(200.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(colorResource(id = R.color.black))
    ) {
        Text("See Promotions")
    }


You can try importing this
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
And then create an image modifier variable
val imageModifier = Modifier.size(120.dp)

Image(
    painter = image,
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
    modifier = imageModifier
)

